# VLC displays black screen for some of my saved pictures

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

After my Windows 10 Creators Update few days ago, my VLC displays black screen for some of my saved pictures. Some of my saved pictures will display in VLC fine though. It seems that I can use the VLC to play my videos fine. It just won't display some of my saved pictures. Anyone with any ideas what may caused the problem ? Any possible solution will be appreciated.

Comment: VLC to view pictures? I didn't even know it did that. Have you tried opening the photos in a different program? Right-click and "open with" and choose another app like the built in photo viewer. Maybe the files are bad and won't open in any application.

Comment: It might be useful to open one and then look at the stream's properties in VLC. This might give a clue as to what the encoding is etc.

Comment: Same here but with Windows 8.  I am running vlc on Linux and on Windows 8.  It displays all images on Linux, but on Windows some of the jpgs display as black.  Same images display fine through web browser, so the files are not "bad".  VLC is great for doing slide shows (and saving them to playlist files), but not if it can't display good jpg files.

Comment: contd...   I checked the file specs as suggested by Appleoddity.  Codec specs are same for files that work and files that don't work.  No significant spec differences according to details provided by ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem as above. Odd number of pixels either v or h or both
seems VLC doesn't like odd number.

In `File Manager`, open file in `Editor (Edit)`, open `Properties`, change file size by one pixel go make odd number even. Either add 1 or subtract 1 and save the file. VLC should be able to playback the file now.

Answer (score 0):

After much testing, I find that for me this happens if the image has either horizontal or vertical resolution of an odd number.  The workaround I use is to crop a 1 pixel strip from left-or-right and/or 1 pixel strip from top-or-bottom, choosing side(s) which is less significant to the image.

Sure wish they would fix VLC, but they don't seem to care much about whether features work, as they haven't fixed broken 'scale' CLI switch, playlist duration setting, and other basic stuff in many years.

Comment: Irfanview is a much better program for image viewing needs IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Select your slideshow or multiple .jpg files
Change the video crop to 1:1 ratio (Crop may be set to "default")

Menu > Video > Crop: Select 1:1 ratio